# Google App & Google Play Services Draining Battery in Cyanogenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery, battery-life, google-play-services, sony-xperia-z

I have an old Sony Xperia Z I want to use in my car to use Spotify/ Google Maps/ Google Navigation/ Android Auto.

The phone is running Cyanogenmod 13.0-20161219-NIGHTLY-yuga / Android 6.0.1 (Marshmallow).

There are hardly any apps installed and I've got pretty much every single power saving feature switched on but the battery is still draining in a little under 24 hours. Google App & Google Play Services make up the bulk of the battery usage.

I've setup the phone to only wakeup when it's charging and go to sleep when it's not - so this battery usage is happening when the phone is (theoretically) asleep.

To complicate things Cyanogenmod is defunct and LineageOS doesn't have support for the Sony Xperia Z.

Is there a known issue with/ fix for this battery drain?

Or should I install another custom ROM (and if so, which one?)

Answer (score 0):

that's common in any custom roms... i have used Cyanogenmod and its normal because they all are not that optimised .... or may be you could try flashing some other kernel.. but i think you will never get better battery backup than stock rom.

Comment: If a phone is old enough to not have even gotten stock Lollipop, won't a custom ROM based on Marshmallow allow for better battery life?